# Coloring the just entered text with the right color

Tags: css, input

I read a lot on the internet but none of them solve my problem:

1. INITIAL
   I have 2 input-fields (name & email) and the initial color must be lightgray:
   NAME  (lighgray)
   EMAIL (lighgray)
2. ENTERING TEXT
   When entering text the color must be black and when focusing to the next field the just filled

JOHN DOE (black when entering text)
EMAIL (lightgray)

1. SUBMIT
   When focussing to the next field (EMAIL or SUBMIT) the name-text is revert into gray bu I like it to stay black.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: That is very unclear questions. Be more specific with code and fiddle demo

Comment: You can use HTML input `placeholder` attribute. Placeholder text usually appears light gray while user entered text appears black (http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ar1uyecc/).

Comment: Wow, I I thought it was clear but hereby

Comment: Wow, I I thought it was clear but here some addition. Frustrated I was  I delete my code but I think that is better because the problem can be solved from scratch.  In summary there are 3 stages: 1) INITIAL, 2) ENTERING TEXT and stage 3 where user goes to next field for entering or submitting. The first stage the color must be lightgray and stage 2 & 3 the text to be entered or already entered must be black. Placeholder seems te be do the trick but whenever text is entered and users are on the next field the enterd text is displayed in lightgray (as defined in the placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that helps you.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#000');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).css('color', grey);
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not handle the second and third case (when focus is on email field and submit button).

Comment: I have updated the solution that works for you exactly as you mentioned. Check it.

Comment: Okay and I believe this is jquery but can you tell me how to implement it

Comment: configure jquery to your site. And above functions inside $(document).ready(function(){    });